# How to get all fish shell commands from a python script?

Tags: python, command, command-line-interface, fish, completion

When I run `complete -C` from my regular terminal fish shell I get a list of ~4k commands, which is great. I want this to happen from my python script. I have the following but it doesn't work:

```py
command = "fish -c 'complete -C'"
    output = (
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode().strip()
    )
```

The output `stdout` is just an empty string. The `stderr` is showing:

```
complete: -C: option requires an argument
Standard input (line 1):
complete -C
(Type 'help complete' for related documentation)"
```

How can I get this to work? Is there something outside of python subprocess I can use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `complete -C` in normal fish prompt it gets converted to complete -C ''

so you have to do:

```
import subprocess
command = "fish -c \"complete -C ''\""
output = (
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout.decode().strip()
)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working with

```py
command = "fish -c 'complete -C \"\"'"
```

Which adds an empty quote as an `arg` so that there is no more `stderr`.

Comment: To explain why that's necessary: `complete -C` will complete the current commandline, only when you haven't started an interactive fish there is no current commandline. So it needs you to give it one.